# put data from my json file in ui-bootstrap carousel

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

i want to my put http json files in slides.push(). so here i used ui.bootstrap.carousel , and i want to set image in my html .

So how can i do it . can someone help me?

```
.controller('dashboardCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location','$timeout', function ($scope, $http, $location, $timeout) {
        $http.get('json/login.json').success(function (data) {
          $scope.info = data.profile[0];
          $scope.pic = data.offers[0];
          console.log($scope.pic);
        })

        $scope.myInterval = 500;
        $scope.noWrapSlides = false;
        $scope.active = 0;
        var slides = $scope.slides = [];
        var currIndex = 0;

        $scope.addSlide = function() {
          // var newWidth = 600 + slides.length + 1;
          slides.push({
            image: '../image/slide1.png',
            id: currIndex++
          },
          {
            image: '../image/slide2.png',
            id: currIndex++
          },
          {
            image: '../image/slide3.png',

            id: currIndex++
          }

          );

        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put your `slides.push`   to `$http.get` function, like here:

```
$scope.get = function() {
        $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'json.json'
            })
                .then(function successCallback(data){
                    $scope.img = data.data;
                       slides.push({
                        image: $scope.img[0].url,
                        id: currIndex++
                      });
                }, function errorCallback(response){
                    console.log(response);
                    console.log('error');
                });
      }
```

Also you can add all `url` from `json.json`  through some kind of `loop` .In my code I am pusshing first `url` from json.
Here is plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/27RvnjGCT5i0MCNooZeB?p=preview